# PHP string not being built in the expected order

Tags: php

I've been working on some code to generate a database driven menu system in PHP which I was able to get working successfully earlier today.
Now however the same function that was working successfully a few hours ago is not working as expected.

The expected output is as follows:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <a href="#" id="navbar-brand-color"class="navbar-brand">Exam Practice</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeader">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeader">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="exam_list.php">Exams</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Maintenance <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="mntn_exam.php">Exams</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mntn_topics.php">Topics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mntn_documents.php">Documents</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mntn_document_type.php">Document Types</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Questions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Question Types</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Answers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mntn_answer_type.php">Answer Types</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mntn_upload.php">Uploads</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And that is what I was getting earlier.
Now however the same function is returning:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="mntn_exam.php">Exams</a></li>
    <li><a href="mntn_topics.php">Topics</a></li>
    <li><a href="mntn_documents.php">Documents</a></li>
    <li><a href="mntn_document_type.php">Document Types</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Questions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Question Types</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Answers</a></li>
    <li><a href="mntn_answer_type.php">Answer Types</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
    <li><a href="mntn_upload.php">Uploads</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <a href="#" id="navbar-brand-color"class="navbar-brand">Exam Practice</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeader">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeader">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="exam_list.php">Exams</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Maintenance <b class="caret"></b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The PHP code generating the above is:

```
function renderMenu($conn, $parentID, $accessLevel) {
// Renders the main menu
// Example use:
//      renderMenu($conn, 0, 80)
// $conn        = Database object
// $parentID    = Which menu does this sub-menu belong to?
// $accessLevel = User's accessLevel, used to determine which menu entries should be displayed
    $menuHTML = '';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblmenu WHERE parentID='$parentID' AND accessLevel <= '$accessLevel' ORDER BY sortOrder";
    if($parentID == 0) { // this should only be done for the top level
        $menuHTML .= '<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">';
        $menuHTML .= '<a href="#" id="navbar-brand-color"class="navbar-brand">Exam Practice</a>';
        $menuHTML .=    '<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeader">';
        $menuHTML .=        '<span class="icon-bar"></span>';
        $menuHTML .=        '<span class="icon-bar"></span>';
        $menuHTML .=        '<span class="icon-bar"></span>';
        $menuHTML .=    '</button>';
        $menuHTML .= '<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeader">';
        $menuHTML .= '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">';
    }
    else {
        $menuHTML .= '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
    }
    $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
        if($row['hasChild'] == true) {
            $menuHTML .= '<li class="dropdown"><a href="'.$row['link'].'" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">'.$row['label'].' <b class="caret"></b></a>';
            $menuHTML .= renderMenu($conn, $row['id'], $accessLevel);
        }
        else {
            $menuHTML .= '<li><a href="'.$row['link'].'">'.$row['label'].'</a>';
        }
        $menuHTML .='</li>';
    }
    $menuHTML .= '</ul>';
    if($parentID == 0) { // add closing div tags
        $menuHTML .= '</div>';
        $menuHTML .= '</div>';
    }
    echo $menuHTML;
}
```

It appears that when the function is called on itself to populate the second `<ul>` block it manages to somehow prepend rather append itself in the appropriate place. Which I think is really odd given that it was working properly in the first place and this code block has not been touched beyond a couple of comments and `echo` statements to help figure out what was going on.

I would appreciate hearing from anyone that has encountered similar behavior before and what steps they took to resolve it.
I'm not asking for suggestions or advice on generating database-driven menu systems (although any tips or constructive criticism you may like to share will be taken on board).
I'm asking "In what situations does PHP prepend a value to a string rather than append it?" and "What are some steps I can take in the future to avoid this happening again?"

For what its worth the page is being hosted in XAMPP, and viewed locally on a Windows 8.1 PC with latest updates installed. The page was tested in both Firefox and Chrome (latest versions of each) with no difference in result between them.

Thanks in advance for your assistance,

Phillip

Comment: What does `renderMenu()` do?

Comment: @mike.k its function used to render menu.

Comment: @Phillip can you show records of table `tblmenu`?

Comment: Oh, I was scrolled too far down to see the function declaration, I'm on board with the answer by @timoh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `renderMenu()` recursively but it's echoing the output instead of returning it. It needs to return `$menuHTML;` instead of echoing it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I needed to fix my problem.  I must have changed that line and not realised it when I was troubleshooting later on.